# Sharepoint Formula summing numbers and skipping N/A

Tags: sharepoint-online

In Sharepoint I have `column 1`, `column 2` and `column 3` with value selection `0,1,2` and `N/A`. I want to write a formula to only sum `column1`, `column2` and `column3` if value is not `N/A`. Default value is `2`

This is the formula I found

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(column1,column2,column3),column1,column2,column3))
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 parameters in the ISNUMBER function, that causes an error

```
=SUM(IF(   ISNUMBER(column1,column2,column3)   ,column1,column2,column3))
```

If you restate your problem:

> Sum 3 columns when 3 columns CAN BE summed

to

> If 3 columns CAN NOT be summed, then the default value = 2

You can rewrite your Formula to

```
=IF( ISERROR(SUM([Column1],[Column2],[Column3])) , 2 , SUM([Column1],[Column2],[Column3]) )
```

This saves you from checking 3 **individual** Columns, and is easier to read and extend

**Note**

Text values are 0 values, so if you have "N/A" as TEXT string in your drop down this won't work.
You then have to check for numbers:

```
= IF(  AND( ISNUMBER([Column1]) , ISNUMBER([Column2]) , ISNUMBER([Column3]))
     , SUM([Column1],[Column2],[Column3])
     , 2
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `ISNA` function specifically for testing something against `N/A`. See documentation on all [IS functions in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IS-functions-586532cc-9888-4ca0-98b8-c874e4c8a087).

You want to know if `ISNA` returns `FALSE` for all field (**no** field is `N/A`). Use [OR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OR-function-9a2a1cca-696f-4d19-a959-3943babd076f). `OR(ISNA([Field1]), ISNA([Field2]), ISNA([Field3]))` will return `TRUE` if **any** field is `N/A`. In that case, from what I've understood, you want to have 2 in calculation.

It's time for [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/IF-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a) then.

```
IF(
    OR(ISNA([Field1]), ISNA([Field2]), ISNA([Field3])),
    2,
    SUM([Field1], [Field2], [Field3])
)
```

This reads like *if any field of three is N/A, return 2, else return a sum of all three*.

You might need to replace `,` with `;` depending on your regional settings.